# import * as queries from "./graphql/queries" fails to find the module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I trying to import a js module to my index.js file in a lambda function. I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot find module '/var/task/graphql/queries' imported from /var/task/index.js
Did you mean to import ../graphql/queries.js?
```

How can I import queries and mutations files to index.js

./index.js

```
import { default as fetch, Request } from "node-fetch";
import * as queries from "./graphql/queries";
import * as mutations from "./graphql/mutations";

async function myFunction(event) {
    // My function body
}

const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
        adminProvision: (event) => {
            return myFunction(event);
        },
    },
};

export const handler = async (event) => {
    //console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    const typeHandler = resolvers[event.typeName];
    if (typeHandler) {
        const resolver = typeHandler[event.fieldName];
        if (resolver) {
            var result = await resolver(event);
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
    throw new Error("Resolver not found!");
};
```

./graphql/queries.js

```
export const ListSmartLocks = /* GraphQL */ `
    query ListSmartLocks(
        $filter: ModelSmartLockFilterInput
        $limit: Int
        $nextToken: String
    ) {
        listSmartLocks(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
            items {
                bikeparkID
            }
            nextToken
        }
    }
`;
```

./graphql/mutation.js

```
export const createSmartLock = /* GraphQL */ `
    mutation CreateSmartLock(
        $input: CreateSmartLockInput!
        $condition: ModelSmartLockConditionInput
    ) {
        createSmartLock(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
            id
            deviceId
            status
            bikeparkID
            vehicleType
            createdAt
            updatedAt
        }
    }
`;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fnadminprovision",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion? It looks like you are trying to import file which is not at the location in the directory tree.

Comment: @Saihaj. Yes. I tried it. But that didn't work.

Comment: What happens if you add `.js` to the end of the import path?

Comment: Hmm `import xxx`, `export const xxx`... This looks like typescript... For NodeJS it's `const queries = require("./graphql/queries");` and `module.exports = createSmartLock;`. Or you could rename the files to `.ts`

Comment: @Pieterjan No, that's just ES6 module syntax. No Typescript-specifics to be found in the question.

Comment: How are you using `index.js`? Can you include the full stacktrace?